# Search for few options in string (if .. in)

Tags: python

So what I'm trying to do is checking if a string contains one of many options.
Let's say I have a `list["bottle", "camera", "cake"]` and I'm trying to check if a string contains one of the options from the list.

I know it's possible using

```
if "bottle" in string...,
```

but how do I do the same thing with few options?

I hope I was able of making my question clear, thx!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
st = "foobar water"   
l = ["bottle", "camera", "cake"] 
if any(w in st for w in l)
```

You may need to split to avoid cases like `foo` being in `foobar` `st.split()`

```
In [10]: st = "foobar bar"   
In [11]: "foo" in st
Out[11]: True    
In [12]: "foo" in st.split()
Out[12]: False
```

`any` will short circuit as soon as we find any word from our wordlist in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
options = {'bottle', 'camera', 'cake'}

if options.issuperset(given_items_to_test):
    # all items in given_items_to_test are found in options

if options.intersection(given_items_to_test):
    # at least one item in given_items_to_test is found in options
```

The [`set.issuperset()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset) tests if `options` is a superset of `given_items_to_test`, while the [`set.intersection()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) can be used to see if there is *at least one item* in from the `options` set used in the items to test.

This works even if `given_items_to_test` is not itself a set, but just a list or tuple:

```
>>> options = {'bottle', 'camera', 'cake'}
>>> given_items_to_test = ['bottle']
>>> options.issuperset(given_items_to_test)
True
>>> given_items_to_test = ['bike']
>>> options.issuperset(given_items_to_test)
False
>>> given_items_to_test = ['bottle', 'camera']
>>> options.issuperset(given_items_to_test)
True
>>> given_items_to_test = ['bottle', 'camera', 'bike']
>>> options.issuperset(given_items_to_test)
False
>>> options.intersection(given_items_to_test)
set(['camera', 'bottle'])
```

Comment: *I'm trying to check if a **string** contains one of the options from the list.*: So I'm guessing `set(options).intersection(the_string.split())` is sufficient

Comment: This doesn't have the behavior OP described; this is checking whether their string contains _only_ words in the word list.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown: ah, sorry, misread your comment. Added the intersection option.

Comment: @JonClements: yeah, you are correct, that wasn't clear to me.